# SharePoint Client Object Model UserFieldValue and [ME] CAML query

Tags: sharepoint

I have run into an weird behavior. Can someone duplicate this to see if it is a bug or if I am doing something wrong

1. Create a List and add a MultiValue Person field, let us call this field Gatekeepers
2. Using Client side object model, create a list item and ensure to populate the field above. I am using the following code

   ```
   List<string> gatekeepers = new List<string>() { @"Domain\User1", @"Domain\User2" }; //User1 is your ID

   var gatekeeperUserValues = gatekeepers
   .Select(loginName => FieldUserValue.FromUser(loginName))
   .ToList();

   item["Gatekeepers"] = gatekeeperUserValues;
   item.Update();
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   ```

So far everything works. The item gets created and the column shows the right value.

Now create a view on the list that uses [Me] as a filter, for example

```
View Name = 'My Items'
Filter = Gatekeepers is equal to [Me]
```

You will find that the view does not return any rows.

Now, edit the item using the standard SharePoint edit interface, do not change any values, just save it back.

This time your 'My Items' view will return correct results, that is the item you created above will be shown in this view

Seems like something is different when person field is updated using CSOM as opposed to using the server side object model.